# Is it possible for entomopter to fly on Mars carrying payload of 1-2kg?

Tags: mars, design

In other words, how big should an [entomopter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomopter) be so that it could fly in Mars' atmosphere and carry a payload of 1-2 kg? I'm trying to find out if an entomopter could be used to carry a spectral sensor camera (special kind of spectral sensor that would be smaller than those already existing). I'm also considering a robotic [ornithopter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter) for that mission. Do you know any other kinds of [MAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_air_vehicle)'s or UAV's suitable for carrying spectral sensors?

Comment: asking for any currently existing devices that can do this on Earth won't be helpful due to Mars 0.6% of Earth air pressure. Designing anything that can fly on Mars is orders of magnitude harder than for Earth.

Comment: The absolute limit in payload for a self-powered aircraft on Mars will depend on many thing, including the particular design, and how many minutes (or seconds) you would like it to stay airborne at a time. Maybe you can add link to a particular engineering desing for entomopter or ornithopter you are thinking of and/or other details, to make the question more answerable. Right now, I think one could build something that could keep 2kg a few centimeters above the surface for a few seconds, but that's probably not what you are looking for

Comment: ...and by the way Welcome to Stackexchange - take [the tour](http://space.stackexchange.com/tour)! Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in FAQ. Then see if you can edit your question and make it less broad.

Comment: Related questions: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19191/why-arent-we-sending-quadcopters-to-mars and http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17176/could-a-helicopter-fly-on-mars . An entomopter has the same performance problems as other aircraft.

Comment: If entomopter, ornithopter or quadrocopter, anything that is not able to fly on earth in a height above 30 km is not useful for Mars.

Comment: @Uwe well it seems that powered [fixed wing craft](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/2278/12102), battery-powered [quadcopters](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19192/12102), [helicopters](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/17185/12102), and yes [entomoters](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19996/12102) can all fly on Mars, we now have a list of things that are able to fly at 30km on Earth!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Hobbes mentioned, there was study funded by the seed program [NASA Institute for Advanced Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Institute_for_Advanced_Concepts) in 2002 to look into the viability of entomopters for Mars exploration.

The results are available [online](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/522Colozza.pdf). The team relied mainly on design analysis, but appears to have built a working version of the vehicle's "reciprocating chemical muscle" (RCM) for a small prototype.

The study's primary design point on page 49 suggests an entomopter with a 1.2m wingspan could have a relative lifting capacity of 1.5kg on Mars. Later, the study clarifies that only some of this mass is available as payload:

> The weight of the RCM system plus a 10 minute fuel charge is on the order of 0.42 kg. **Based on Table 3-2, this would leave 1.08 kg for mission payload equipment.**

The RCM system in the proposed entomopter uses fuel, not electricity, meaning a user looking for more than 10 minutes of flight would have to sacrifice even more payload mass.

The study itself suggests using in-situ resource production to help overcome this, but this is itself another unproven technology. Even returning to a refueling station containing stockpiled fuel seems likely to be difficult - the proposed vehicle is not capable of hovering, making a precision landing unlikely.

In conclusion: it seems plausible that an entomopter could one day lift a payload on the scale you describe on Mars, but the vehicle does not seem like a great fit for the current model of slow, long term robotic exploration. To my knowledge, NASA has not funded a follow-up study for the concept.

Answer (score 3):

[This study](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/522Colozza.pdf) suggests that an entomopter with reasonable wingspan (on the order of 1 m) could achieve a 1 kg payload, if powered by a highly efficient engine running on e.g. hydrazine.

> Based on the research conducted during this NIAC Phase II study, a design space has been identified in which Mars Entomopter flight is practical.